# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable error?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch

I studying on a model training. when i called the training function i got this error "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable" and i can't see where i missed it.

here is my calling function:

```
train(
            model,
            optimizer,
            loss,
            train_loader,
            hyperparams["epoch"],
            scheduler=hyperparams["scheduler"],
            device=hyperparams["device"],
            val_loader=val_loader,
```

)
[the error i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEZTG.png)

Comment: I think you need to add your valid and train loaders please to be easily debugged.

Comment: @Phoenix it has nothing to do with the loader

Comment: please do not post screenshots of logs/stack traces/code. Instead copy-paste the relevant text and format it properly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling `tqdm` module, instead of `tqdm` method from `tqdm` module.

Replace:

```
import tqdm
```

with:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
```

Comment: had similar issue with glom

Comment: had similar issue with glob